# Touch Creates File with Different Owner

Tags: permissions

I'm connecting to my Raspberry Pi using SSH as user mike.  I use touch to create a file in a directory whose owner pi / users.  Both mike and pi are in group users.  The newly created file has owner pi / users.  I would think it would be mike / users.

```
$ ls -l ..
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 1 pi users 4096 Feb 12 15:03 parent_dir
$ touch z
$ ls -l z                                             
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi users 0 Feb 12 15:03 z
```

Is this expected behavior? Why isn't the owner mike / users?

Comment: Did the file exist before? If so, only the timestamp got changed. If not, what does `id -un` say? Or, are `id -u mike` and `id -u pi` equal?

Comment: The file did not exist before.  `id -un` says `mike`.  The ids of mike and pi are not equal.  Thx for the attention/reply...

Comment: Perhaps you have setgid on the directory.  Can you `stat -c "%a %U:%G %n" parent_dir`?

Comment: Results of `ls -ld qq ; touch qq ; ls -ld qq ; id -u ; id -u pi` please. Or for some other file than `qq` for which the first `ls` returns a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: `stat` results: `775 pi:users parent_dir/`

Comment: the ls results: `ls: cannot access qq: No such file or directory` then  `-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi users 0 Feb 15 11:33 qq` then `1001` then `1000`

Comment: Is this a local filesystem or a remotely mounted one? (If in doubt, output from `df -h .`)

Comment: I'm remoting into a Raspberry Pi via SSH.  The dir I'm creating the files in with `touch` is on an external hard drive on the Pi.

Comment: Ah now we're getting somewhere. What filesystem type?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell that from the cli.  I think it's ntfs.

Comment: `mount | grep -F "$(df -h . | awk 'NR>1{print $NF}')"`

Comment: So...guessing here.  You have the ntfs share mounted with the user 'pi' in samba?  That might account for the inherited ownership and we'd need to look at the smb.conf.

Comment: @jayson child directories of `parent_dir` are shared with samba

Comment: mount output: `/dev/sda2 on /media/parent_dir type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)`